# how can I add checked row in to data table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing code in check box click event of a grid view(gvrow). with following code

But my checked rows should alone come to data table(dt).if any row un checked after checked it should not come to data table.

The code I shown below is adding the row but not checked one

```
protected void chkCall_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvDetails.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkCall");
        if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
        {

            //dt.Rows.Add();
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["shopno"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
            row["Lineitem"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            row["Suppliername"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            row["Dunsnumber"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
            row["AgingDays"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
            // row["lastfollowupmail"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            i++;
        }

    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your `i++` outside checkbox condition.

```
protected void chkCall_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvDetails.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkCall");
        if (chk != null & chk.Checked)
        {

            //dt.Rows.Add();
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["shopno"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
            row["Lineitem"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            row["Suppliername"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            row["Dunsnumber"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
            row["AgingDays"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
            // row["lastfollowupmail"] = gvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
        i++;

    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code you can try this

Suppose your checkbox column is named *ChkBox*:

```
  DataTable tbl = ((DataTable)GridView1.DataSource).Clone();//Clone structure first
  var rows = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>()
                         .Where(r=>Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["ChkBox"].Value))
                         .Select(r=>((DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem).Row);
  foreach(var row in rows)
  tbl.ImportRow(row);
```